# Dynamic view with sysobjects tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to alter a view using a T-SQL script dynamic. Each month I have a new table in my database, I want to include the new table in my view. My idea is to create a var inside a T-SQL procedure and then build the sql statment to create the code I will use to alter the view. With this I only need to EXEC (@SqlView). The challenge now is to get (@SqlResults) in a string. Any ideas?

```
SQL for the view (@SqlView)
select a, b from table01
union all
select a, b from table02
union all
select a, b from table03

SQL statement for the view code (@SqlResults)
select 'select a,b from '+so.name' union all' from    sysobjects so
join    sys.schemas s
        On  so.uid = s.schema_id
where   so.xtype = 'U'
and so.name like '%table0%'
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute dynamic SQL that will alter your view, or do you want to execute dynamic SQL that will return the results from your tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach that doesn't use a loop.

```
declare @SqlResults nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SqlResults = @SqlResults + 'select a,b from ' + t.name + ' union all ' 
from sys.tables t
where t.name like '%table0%'

select @SqlResults = 'ALTER VIEW SomeView as ' + left(@SqlResults, LEN(@SqlResults) - 10)

select @SqlResults
--Uncomment the exec line when you are comfortable
--exec sp_executesql @SqlResults
```

Comment: No loop needed, this is it Sean!

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL that I use when trying to generate a script for every table, altered to plug in your specific details:

```
DECLARE @SQLTable TABLE
  (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Sequel VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL
  )

INSERT INTO @SQLTable (Sequel)

SELECT 
'SELECT A, B FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + ' UNION ALL'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%table0%'



DECLARE @Looper INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @SQLTable)
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0 
DECLARE @ExecSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 
    --'' -- use this if you just want to run the SQL
    'ALTER VIEW MyView AS 
    ' -- use this if you want to alter a view

WHILE @Counter <= @Looper 
  BEGIN
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
    SELECT @ExecSQL = @ExecSQL + '
    ' + Sequel 
    FROM @SQLTable
    WHERE ID = @Counter 


  END


SET @ExecSQL = 
    LEFT (@ExecSQL, LEN(@ExecSQL) - 10) -- the LEFT() function is to remove the final UNION ALL
    + '

GO'
PRINT (@ExecSQL)
```

Comment: This will work but a loop is not the best choice. We can do this without a loop.

Comment: @SeanLange, feel free to post a better answer - like I said, this is what I use at the moment.  Generally, I'm running this against a couple of dozen tables at most, and given that it runs in less than a second, I've never felt the need to rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks AHiggins, I think the solution from Sean is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a way to do this with cursors, but I'm not too familiar with that syntax. What I've done in similar situations is used a few variables and either a table variable or a temp table. I also don't have much opportunity to work with dynamic sql very much, so this is a bit of a shot in the dark.

```
declare   @view_script as varchar(4000) = 'alter view dbo.my_view as select a, b from table01'
declare   @cur_table as integer = 2
declare   @table_list as table (table_num integer identity(1,1), table_nm varchar(100))

insert into @table_list (table_nm)
select name
from   sys.tables
where  name like '%table0%'

while  @cur_table <= (select max(table_num) from @table_list)
begin
select @view_script = @view_script + 'union all ' + char(10) + select a, b from ' + table_nm
from   @table_list
where  @table_list.table_num = @cur_table

@cur_table = @cur_table + 1
end

exec @view_script
```

Let me know if this works or if there was something you had to change to make it work.

Comment: No need to use a while loop or a cursor here at all.

Comment: This solution is also valid, I think the one from Sean is cleaner. Thanks!